# Changing datatype of column from object to float in Kaggle

Tags: python, object, types, kaggle

I have a column in my dataset (Expenses) that is currently of type object and i would like to chnage it to float so that i can create graphs from it.

The column currently looks like :
['12','+30','7865',30.0,9998948894, 23.2, '12.8']

How can i convert them all to show:
[12.0 30.0 7865.0 30.0 23.2 12.8]

I have tried this:

```
df['Expenses'] = df['Expenses'].astype(str).str.replace('+', '')
df_clean = df.dropna()
df_clean = df_clean[df_clean["Expenses"] != 'nan']
df_clean = df_clean[df_clean["Expenses"] != '9998948894']
df_clean['Expenses'] = df_clean['Expenses'].astype(float)
```

however it places each data into the form of 12.000000e+01

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_numeric` here to convert the `column` to `float`, here is how you could do it

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# Clean the Expenses column
df['Expenses'] = df['Expenses'].astype(str).str.replace('+', '') # Remove the plus sign
df_clean = df.dropna() # Remove any rows with missing values
df_clean = df_clean[df_clean["Expenses"] != 'nan'] # Remove any rows with Expenses value 'nan'
df_clean = df_clean[df_clean["Expenses"] != '9998948894'] # Remove any rows with Expenses value '9998948894'

# Convert the Expenses column to float
df_clean['Expenses'] = df_clean['Expenses'].astype(float)
```